# ArgoCD getting started tutorial: certificate error x509 when adding the example application

Tags: kubernetes, networking, argocd

I'm following the [ArgoCD's getting started tutorial](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/) and I struggle to add a simple application from the repository example.
With the command:

```
rgocd app create guestbook --repo https://github.com/argoproj/argocd-example-apps.git --path guestbook --dest-server https://kubernetes.default.svc --dest-namespace default
```

I got the result:

> FATA[0000] rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = application spec for guestbook is invalid: InvalidSpecError: repository not accessible: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error testing repository connectivity: Get "https://github.com/argoproj/argocd-example-apps.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack": x509: certificate is valid for 320a840bb19e071a59eb794607e1bf64.79f1460424a4cdb0e35d7e968c7fa927.traefik.default,

not github.com and I don't understand why this is coming up. Do you have any idea of what I would need to do to have this working ?

I have also tried over ssh and got this error :

> Unknown desc = error testing repository connectivity: Repository 'ssh://git@github.com:argoproj/argocd-example-apps.git' cannot be initialized, because its root would be system temp at /tmp

Answer (score 0):

Check your network, as you can see you are getting cert for 320a840bb19e071a59eb794607e1bf64.79f1460424a4cdb0e35d7e968c7fa927.traefik.default instead of git's endpoint. Try to make a git request from pod over https

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).